# HTML page getting distorted in Android webview, Same is working in iOS webview

Tags: android

HTML page getting distorted in Android webview, Same is working in iOS webview.
UI is getting distorted in android webview as per device resolution.

Comment: no code, no page examples, no screens. do you think it is fine?

Comment: the user agent information may be also useful

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to setup [viewport](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html) properly.